# R error occurs when assgin a vector to an array

Tags: arrays, r, vector

I have coding of a function in R as following:

```
  matching_score=function(nitems, tot.score) {

  nInterval <- 4*nitems+1
  tot <- array(0, dim=c(nInterval,2,nGroup.all) )
  minimum <- nitems
  maximum <- nitems*5
  tot[,1,] <- c(minimum: maximum)    
    for (nGcut in 1:nGroup.all)
    {
```

...
But R gave an error message as :
Error in tot[, 1, ] <- c(minimum:maximum) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
How can I solve this issue? When minimum and maximum were actual numbers, the error was not presented.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: I recommend creating a complete function (seems that the 'for' loop is not needed for your question) and including a call, ending up with a reproducible example.

Comment: You still need to actually call the function for this to be a reproducible example.  And what's nGroup.all?  Also, as I mentioned above, as the error occurs just before the 'for' loop, you (probably) do not need anything after that in the function.

Comment: Have a look here for help on how to create a [great reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found the error occurred because of nGroup.all, which should have specified as integer rather than a vector.

Comment: Also, the great reproducible example in R is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably occurs when you try to `cbind` the tot object. The error message is complaining about dimensions. You are using "[" as if this object is an array with three dimensions and 'cbind' will not work with arrays. If it's really a three dimensional object the install package 'abind' and use function `abind`.

```
require(abind)
arr <- array(1:(2*3*4), c(4,3,2) )
abind(arr, arr[,,1], along=3)
```

The dimensions of this line:

```
tempo[nRw,] <- cbind(tot[nRw,1,1], sum(tot[nRw,2,]))
```

... seem all wrong. The LHS has two dimensions, the 'tot' object has three and the return from sum will be a scalar.